# Where to check Javascript's JSON.parse() error log on dev-tools?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-devtools

I am new to Javascript trying to create a project that uses JSON.parse() function.  My code runs successfully however `JSON.parse` dint work and didn't return any error on the dev tools console log.

I tried to debug my code with:

```
console.log("Test log1#######")
console.log(JSON.parse(json));
console.log("Test log2#######")
```

On the console.log i can only see `"Test log1#######"`. but not the `"Test log2#######"` which means code fails at line two but without printing any error on Devtools console as it does normally. But I am sure the code is failing due to some JSON validation issue but I can't see the. error anywhere on dev tools.

Please suggest a method to explore the error log of JSON.parse()

thanks

Comment: You can wrap it inside a `try/catch`

Comment: Are you sure you haven't disabled _"Errors"_ in the [console reporting levels](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/reference/#level)?

Comment: Do you have error level logging enabled in your devtools? Do you see "red" entry when calling `console.error(1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do :

```
try{
  JSON.parse(badFormat);
}catch(err){
  console.log(err);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Most probably your "json" string is undefined

Try using the reviver parameter to see what is coming out of the json string. JSON.parse() spits out the error in the console tab of the browser if it finds the issue with the passed string

```js
JSON.parse('your string', (key, value) => {
  console.log(key); // log the current property name, the last is "".
  return value;     // return the unchanged property value.
});
```

[MDN JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).